# sync event on multiple html5 devices without setting up node server

Tags: javascript, html, synchronization, multi-user

How do I sync the change of color on multiple usersessions?

I have a lot of computers, and would like to make a webpage that makes all the screens change color simultanously (to the eye) every second or so.

The effect should be like a discolight, all screens show red, then show green, then show blue.

Making a javascript that changes the color is not a great deal, but getting it in sync is.

I would really like to do it without using a node server (the best related solution I could find on StackExchange), but is that at all possible?

Would it help if all the computers were synched to the same ntp-server or is that irrelevant?

Thank you for any help or pointers.

Comment: No. You will need to use a node server. Getting things to be in sync can be tricky and that's your best bet.

Comment: It doesn't have to be node, but a web socket server (written in whatever language/enviorment) would probably be the most optimal solution.

Comment: synch it via the current time stamp? Divide the JS time (it is in Millis if I remember correctly) by 1000 to counteract any clock skewing then divide by 10 to gain 10 different colors (or divide by 5 or whatever).